# Regex to check if exact string exists

Tags: php, regex, exact-match

I am looking for a way to check if an exact string match exists in another string using Regex or any better method suggested. I understand that you tell regex to match a space or any other non-word character at the beginning or end of a string. However, I don't know exactly how to set it up.

Search String: `t`

String 1: `Hello World, Nice to see you! t`
String 2: `Hello World, Nice to see you!`
String 3: `T Hello World, Nice to see you!`

I would like to use the search string and compare it to String 1, String 2 and String 3 and only get a positive match from String 1 and String 3 but not from String 2.

Requirements:
Search String may be at any character position in the Subject.
There may or may not be a white-space character before or after it.
I do not want it to match if it is part of another string; such as part of a word.

For the sake of this question:
I think I would do this using this pattern: `/\bt\b/gi`

`/\b{$search_string}\b/gi`

Does this look right? Can it be made better? Any situations where this pattern wouldn't work?
Additional info: this will be used in PHP 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion of `/\bt\b/gi` will work and is probably the way to go. You've correctly used `\b` for word boundaries. You're using the global and case-insensitive modifiers which will find all matches in both cases. Simple, straight forward, clean. Look no further than what you've already come up with.

Comment: @Jayrox: `#` is not a "word character" so it's impossible for `\b` to consider it to be a word boundary. Introducing the `#` transforms your question enough that I would consider it a new question. Please post a new question about matching `#t`.

Comment: new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827992/regex-to-check-if-exact-string-exists-including

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to me. You might want to check the exact meaning of [the \b assertion](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php) to make sure it's exactly what you need.

Can't really name any situation where this pattern "wouldn't work" without a more elaborate description, but `\b` would work fine for your testcases.

Answer (score 1):

According to the old saying give a man a reg expression and he is happy for a day, teach him to write regular expression and he is happy for a lifetime (or something to that effect) try out the "[regulato](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/)r"

It provides a GUI and some pretty good examples for reg exp needs.