# Regex to check if exact string exists including #

Tags: php, regex

New question As suggested by Asaph in previous question: [Regex to check if exact string exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824291/regex-to-check-if-exact-string-exists)

I am looking for a way to check if an exact string match exists in another string using Regex or any better method suggested. I understand that you tell regex to match a space or any other non-word character at the beginning or end of a string. However, I don't know exactly how to set it up.

Search String: `#t`

Should Match:
String 1: `Hello World, Nice to see you! #t`
String 2: `#T Hello World, Nice to see you!`
String 3: `Hello World, #t Nice to see you!`

Should not Match:
String 1: `Hello World, Nice to see you!`
String 2: `Hello World, Nice to see you! #ta`
String 3: `#tHello World, Nice to see you!`

Edit 2: Added more string samples

Edit 1 for Serg555 and SilentGhost:
Characters allowed in search string:
`#[_a-zA-Z0-9]`
`#` is optional.

Requirements:
Search String may be at any character position in the Subject.
There may or may not be a white-space character before or after it.
I do not want it to match if it is part of another string; such as part of a word.

For the sake of this question: I think I would do this using this pattern: `/\b\#t\b/gi`
However, this is not returning the results as I would have expected.

I am able to find the exact matches for normal strings (strings where # isn't present) using:

`/\b{$search_string}\b/gi`

Additional info: this will be used in PHP 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is:

```
/(?:^|\s)#t\b/i           #t is in the beginning or preceded by space.
```

`\b` matches word border, which is a border between word-characters and non-word characters. `#` is a non-word character, therefore your regex matches only strings like this: `abc#t`, or `ab_#t`.

Also, normally `#` is not a special character in regex, you don't need to escape it.

**ETA**: Your requirements are rather ambiguous: *There may or may not be a white-space character before or after it. I do not want it to match if it is part of another string; such as part of a word.*

1. no white space character before or after? so there will be a non white-space character?
2. but how is it separated then from other strings? what characters are allowed?

I think you need to give a comprehensive sample of your possible input strings. Because, as it is my regex works just fine.

Comment: what if i only want it to match `#t` but not `abc#t` or `#ta`?

Comment: This one would also match abc#t, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @serg: I don't think that OP has such a problem

Comment: What do you mean? He just wrote it in the first comment.

Comment: This one wouldn't match `abc,#t` :p

Comment: Anyway, this answer is probably better now, just OP needs to manually list all characters that can be matched before the word, according to their needs.

Comment: @serg, I only plan on allowing the # to be present at the start of a string.

Comment: serg, i've added the characters I plan on allowing to the original question.

Comment: @SilentGhost, I have updated the question with answers to your questions

Comment: @Jayrox: well, my regex works, even its previous version did.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give it a try in a few.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(?!\b)#t\b/si`

Comment: Yep, using \b for searching non-word characters is not the best idea. But still it would make less false matches than `#t\b`

Comment: this one? no, only in your case of `&#t`