# Check if URL has an exact string with PHP

Tags: php, string, url

I've tried the following:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'car') !== false) {
    echo 'Car exists.';
} else {
    echo 'No cars.';
}
```

However if the url contains the word "care" or "car2" it will also trigger "Car Exists". How do I get a match if only "car" is found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to check if exact string exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824291/regex-to-check-if-exact-string-exists)

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, but how would I apply that solution to my example?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```php
if (strpos($url,'car') !== false) {
```

into

```php
if (preg_match('/\bcar\b', $url) !== 0) {
```

Basically, you search for word `car` with no other alphanumeric surrounding it.

---

Hope this helps!